# try-except and a list of dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary, try-except

I have a list of dictionaries to describe the format. I would like to print only "US" using try/except construct. Because I might have more lists, which don't have a "nationality" tag. I only think of if/else construct. Please help me. Thanks!

```
list_components = js['results'][0]['list_components']
    try:
        for item in list_components:
            item["types"] == ["nationality", "political"]
            print('The nationality information for the list:', item["short_name"])
                          
    except:
        print('No nationality is available for this list.')
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `if`? The purpose of `try` is exception handling and not regular control flow.

Comment: Exactly. My professor wants to use only try/except. It's killing me

Comment: Is the condition to print only "US" (in the short_name field I assume) or all entries that have a nationality?

Comment: Nationality can be changed for each entries and sometimes not appeared. Thanks

Comment: Hey @JIAK , did you check my answer? tell me if its not ok for you...

Comment: If you want to use the error handling mechanism, you have to trigger an error, e.g. by trying to access a field that doesn't exist. You can then catch the specific error and print out a message or ignore and move on. If you want to force it, you could `raise` an error when the condition is not true but that seems pointless.

Comment: No need to use try/except for what you are trying to do. Iterate over all items one by one and do `print("The nationality information for the list:", item["short_name"]) if "nationality" in item["types"] else print("No nationality is available for this list.")`.

As @JanWilamowski mentioned, try/catch is for error handling, in that case, you will have to give reason to the program when to crash. Wich is when no nationality is found.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree and I want to use the if/else construct. But this is homework my prof wants us to use try/except. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very naive approach to what you want to achieve. But this is not considered a good practice. It's like making something out of something and ignoring all the good rules programmers adopt.

```py
list_components = js['results'][0]['list_components'] 

for item in list_components:
    try:
        #Generate error when there is no nationality otherwise print nationality 
        status = item["types"][0] == "nationality"
        status and print("Nationality: ", item["short_name"])
        raise ValueError
    except:
        #Print prompt
        not status and print("No Nationality")
```

This solution does not require any try/catch construct and can be solved purely with if-else. In case anyone else needs it, here is a better and simple solution.

```
for item in list_components:
    print("Nationality: " item["short_name"]) if item["types"][0] == "nationality" else print("No Nationality")
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with if construct, but this is what my prof wants it :(

Answer (score 0):

Too big to post it as a comment, so i posted it as an answer,

Is this code ok for you? I mean, the `try, except` does absolutely nothing here... But tell me if this is not what you want

```
list_components = js['results'][0]['list_components']
try:
    for item in list_components:
        item["short_name"] == 'US' and item["types"] == ["nationality", "political"] and print('The nationality information for the list:', item["short_name"])
                      
except:
    print('No nationality is available for this list.')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. But 'US' can be changed depending on the input. I will try and operation though!